How to Play Real-Time INT32 PCM Audio Data received from Socket.io in Swift?
I'm working on a Swift application where I receive real-time INT32 PCM audio data through a socket.io connection. The specifications of the audio data are as follows:
Size: 256 bytes
Bit Depth: 32-bit
Channels: 2 (stereo)
Sample Rate: 4000 samples per second
I'm looking for a way to play this audio data in my Swift application.
Could someone provide guidance or an example of how to set this up? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried looking into MobileVLCKit, AVAudioEngine and AudioQueue, but I'm not sure how to handle the specific format and real-time playback. I've read some articles and forums suggesting to use circular buffer, but I don't know how to implement it.

This is probably too large a question for Stack Overflow. There's a lot to cover for this format. But Apple provides pretty solid example code using AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer, which is pretty solid for this kind of work. It's my preferred tool to build custom players from scratch. The example code won't get you all of the way there (especially the complexities of streaming and particularly dealing with dropped packets), but it'll get you started. Like I said, it's a big topic. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/playing_custom_audio_with_your_own_player

@RobNapier Thanks! I've done the part that deals with socket.io and I'm getting a steady stream from it. Just the part of getting it to play is the issue.

Then the link there will get you on the right path. "A steady stream" isn't really a thing with a network connection. You're going to need to deal with packets coming in at inconsistent timings, and even being late or dropped, and you'll need to deal with that; but you'll get there once you write the basic form based on the sample code. Best of luck with it.
